# Error after closing Window Modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

have a problem in all Views of my Platform with respect to the Modal that is what I come to see.
Open and close Perfectly. The problem is when I close it.
I have a Button to hide the Side Menu

This is the Menu Hide button:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

and it does not work after closing it, I also happened to a Dropdown that had not worked but Fixed otherwise.

This is Admin Button Dropdown

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

What can be the problem that I have?

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-md btnAlta">Nuevo Cliente</button>

   !-- Modal -->
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-
        labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
         <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="modal-content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(".btnAlta").click(function (eve) {

        $("#modal-content").load("@Url.Action("ClientesAlta","Clientes")");
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    })
```

Solution:
Library jquery duplicated when export from two layout and generating error after close Modals and click on Menue

Comment: You'll have to explain it better, buddy. Are you aware that your code is trying to replace all `modal-content` contents after every single click, right?

Comment: The error is solved.
Library duplicated when export from two layout and generating error after close Modals and click on Menue

Comment: You can write your solution as an answer instead of having it inside the question

Comment: Yes, as @AmrElgarhy mentioned, you should write the solution in an answer. Then, just approve your own answer. This way we'll have this question closed. Please do that. Thanks.

Comment: Solution: Library jquery duplicated when export from two layout and generating error after close Modals and click on Menue

Answer (score 1):

***Solution***: Library jquery duplicated when export from two layout and generating error after close Modals and click on Menue